# AWS Cognito User Pool Console shows e-mail has been verified but Android logcat shows email_verified is returning false

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

I/System.out: email 
06-29 12:47:20.387 5391-5391/com.amazonaws.youruserpools.CognitoYourUserPoolsDemo I/System.out: given_name 
06-29 12:47:20.387 5391-5391/com.amazonaws.youruserpools.CognitoYourUserPoolsDemo I/System.out: phone_number_verified true
06-29 12:47:20.387 5391-5391/com.amazonaws.youruserpools.CognitoYourUserPoolsDemo I/System.out: phone_number 
06-29 12:47:20.387 5391-5391/com.amazonaws.youruserpools.CognitoYourUserPoolsDemo I/System.out: email_verified false

Verified Sender: Email  Status

-my email-  verified

From https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=us-east-1#verified-senders-email:

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide any details on the user-pool and the user? What is the status of the email verification, shown on the user details screen in the sample app?

P.S. Do not post valid email-id's or phone numbers in this public forum.